# Explosion of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am considering a Markov chain i continunous time  on the countable state space $S=\lbrace 0 \rbrace\cup \lbrace (i,j) \mid i \in \lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F \rbrace , j \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$. The transistion intensities are gived by

\begin{align}
q_{(i,j),(i,j+1)} & =j\beta_i,& j\in \mathbb{N},\ i\in \lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F \rbrace \\
q_{(i,j),(i,j-1)} & =j\delta_i,& j\geq 2,\ i\in \lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F \rbrace\\
q_{(i,1),0} & =\delta_i,& i\in \lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F \rbrace\\
q_{0,(i,1)} & =1,& i\in\lbrace A,B,C,D,E,F \rbrace
\end{align}

Now my problem is to give a heuristic argument that explosion does not occur for instance by giving a lower bound on the expected time of the n-th jump of the Markov chain.

I have drawn the transition diagram for the chain, and I understand the structure of the process, but I can't get on with the problem.

I have a theorem which says that explosion is possible iff

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\beta_i}+\frac{\delta_i}{\beta_i\beta_{i-1}} + \cdots + \frac{\delta_i\cdots \delta_1}{\beta_i\cdots \beta_0}<\infty$$

where $\beta_i=q_{i,i+1}$, $\delta_{i+1}=q_{i+1,i}$ and $-(\beta_{i+1}+\delta_{i+1})=q_{i+1,i+1}$ are the intensities for the process, but I cant find the right expression for the sum. I hope someone can help!

Comment: To call $\beta_i$ and $\delta_i$ the parameters used to describe the chain on $S$ is the most misleading choice one can imagine when compared to the statement of the theorem you recall later on... Let me suggest to change this and then to solve the question in the case where $\beta_A=\beta_B=\ldots=b$ and $\delta_A=\delta_B=\ldots=d$ for some fixed $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a good notation. I am just confused which parameters to be included in the sum and which indices?

Comment: Precisely, these bad notations are probably causing at least part of your confusion, hence my suggestion (which you do not want to follow, it seems?).

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. So I get the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j \cdot b} + \frac{d}{(j-1)b^2}+\frac{d^2}{(j-2)b^3}+ ...+ \frac{d^{j-1}}{b^j}$. Is that correct?